# background binding with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following knockout bindings...

```
       <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: $parent.levels">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <img alt="level" class="pic" data-bind="attr:{src: '../../Content/images/levels/' + $index() + '.png'}" />
                <button class="btn btn-default piclabels" data-bind="click:$parent.startingLevel.bind($parent,$index()),text:$data,css:{active:$parent.startingLevel() == $index()}"></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I want to remove the img tag and instead apply background images to the button.  I have tried multiple examples all over the web, including from knockout, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
data-bind="style: {background: 'url('../../Content/images/levels/' + $index() + '.png')' repeat-none left}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `style` binding, each style needs to return a string for the whole value. So if you are using single quotes such as in a url you need to escape them using backslash `\`. Instead of `repeat-none`, I think you meant to use `no-repeat`.

```
data-bind="style: {background: 'url(\'../../Content/images/levels/' + $index() + '.png\') no-repeat left' }"
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbzpykeL/)